# Focus out event People Picker

Tags: javascript, clientpeoplepicker

I want to do some operation when focus is lost from `<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker>`. Is there is any event like `FocusOut` or any other event.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using client side people picker with div as [explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx):

```
<div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
```

You can set the `blur` event on peoplePickerDiv using jQuery as following:

```
  $("#peoplePickerDiv").blur(function(e){
      // Your operation here
  });
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be true. can anyone confirm?

Comment: what does seem to be true is that 2 levels of divs down, this class is added and removed: sp-peoplepicker-topLevelFocus